# How to get values from RDD in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, rdd

I want to read the contents of zipfile stored at particular location.
So i used `SparkContext.readFile` method as shown below :

```
val zipFileRDD = sc.binaryFiles("./handsOn/repo~apache~storm~14135470~false~Java~master~2210.zip")

zipFileRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream)] = ./handsOn/repo~apache~storm~14135470~false~Java~master~2210.zip BinaryFileRDD[4] at binaryFiles at <console>:21
```

My Questtion is :

**How to get `PortableDataStream` instance from this RDD.**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`collect` action](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions): `zipFileRDD.collect` will return an `Array[(String, PortableDataStream)]`. But that's normally not what you actually want! If you then read files using these instances, you aren't actually using Spark's capabilities: everything happens in your driver program. Instead, apply `map` and other transformations so that different files get read on different workers.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the PortableDataStream outside of an RDD, then just run:

```
val zipFilePds = zipFileRDD.map(x => x._2).collect()
```

Using the Apache Commons Compress library, you can do something like this to get at the contents of the zip file (in this case the file listing):

```
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip

val zipFileListing = zipFileRDD.map(x => x._2.open()).map(x => { val y = new ZipArchiveInputStream(x) ; y.getNextEntry().getName() }).collect()
```